# Error en android studio ":app:processDebugResources"

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola estoy iniciando en andriod studio y estoy teniendo un problema al momento de querer compilar mi proyecto, ya busque documentacion y videos, no puedo resolverlo quisiera saber como hacerlo ya que si me urge bastante poder hacer correr la app.

--Error--
:app:processDebugResources
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.9.6 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.9.6) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
failed linking references.
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
failed linking references.
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
Duplicate class found

A lo que e visto es un problema de duplicidad de dependencias algo asi, que tambien son las dependencias externas Agrego mis dependencias del gradle que tengo:

dependencies {

```
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7")
implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
//Dependencias de FireBase
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.2")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")


androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
```

}